# A set with compound value and fast search for value elements

Tags: data-structures

I'm looking for a data structure that is similar to a set which stores compound values consisting of 4 integers: `i1`, `i2`, `i3`, `i4`. This data structure should have fast look up time, but it should also allow for fast deleting of members with a particular i3 and i4. So `delete_a(x)` should delete all the members with `i3 = x` and `delete_b(x)` should delete all the members with `i4 = x`.The most critical is member look up operation, so I'd like it to be O(1) if possible. The values of `i1`, `i2`, `i3`, and `i4` are rather large, so I cannot use a 4 dimensional array because it will take too much memory. I thought that maybe some combination of a hash table and auxiliary lists can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want absolute speed, while maintaining some memory efficiency I would do this:

```
HashMap_a:
  Key: i3
  Value: List of Hash(i1,i2,i3,i4)
HashMap_b:
  Key: i4
  Value: List of Hash(i1,i2,i3,i4)
HashMap:
  Key: Hash(i1,i2,i3,i4)
  Value: (i1,i2,i3,i4)
```

`delete_a` is simply a matter of getting the list from `HashMap_a` and removing from HashMap the elements whose keys are in the list. Likewise for `delete_b`
Look-ups are O(1) from `HashMap`